# Erro instalando apache2 no Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Estou sem conseguir instalar o apache2 no Ubuntu.
Tentei este comando:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-passenger
```

Porém retorna o seguinte erro no final da instalação:

```
Configurando libapache2-mod-passenger (4.0.37-2) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-passenger (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 libapache2-mod-passenger
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

O que preciso fazer? :\

Comment: Analisando a resposta do terminal, o seu problema não tá na instalação do apache2 em si, mas sim na instalação do libapache2-mod-passenger. Creio que esse material possa lhe ser de grande ajuda nessa missão, segue o link: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/trusty/

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Weslley.

O erro agora mudou. Quando eu chamo:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger

Retorna o seguinte:

Configurando libapache2-mod-passenger (4.0.37-2) ...
apache2_invoke: Enable module passenger
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
apache2_reload: Your configuration is broken. Not restarting Apache 2

Comment: Consegui resolver tudo através das seguinte sequência de comandos:
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Na verdade, eu acho que foi isto, pois testei muitas coisas.

Answer (score 2):

Para instalar o apache2 no ubuntu, utilize o seguinte comando: `sudo apt-get install apache2`. Veja a referência [aqui](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado, por favor, marque-a como correta clicando na seta verde acima do número da resposta. Obrigado